# Call to a member function format() on boolean - Laravel

Tags: php, datetime, boolean, laravel-5.3

I am getting:

"Call to a member function format() on boolean
*in UploadController.php line 87*"

This is row 58 to 93, with 87 being bold :

```
    set_time_limit(120);
    $now = (new \DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $nowYmd = (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $deviceLog = [];
        $deviceLog['installation_id'] = $this->parseForNull((int)$row[0]);
        $deviceLog['device_id'] = $devicesSerialToId[$row[1]];
        $deviceLog['2'] = $this->parseForNull($row[2]);
        $deviceLog['3'] = $this->parseForNull($row[3]);
        $deviceLog['4'] = $row[4];
        $deviceLog['5'] = $this->parseForNull($row[5]);
        $deviceLog['6'] = $this->parseForNull($row[6]);
        $deviceLog['7'] = $this->parseForNull($row[7]);
        $deviceLog['8'] = $this->parseBoolean($row[8]);
        $deviceLog['9'] = $this->parseBoolean($row[9]);
        $deviceLog['10'] = $this->parseBoolean($row[10]);
        $deviceLog['11'] = $this->parseForNull(intval($row[11]));
        $deviceLog['12'] = $this->parseForNull($row[12]);
        $deviceLog['13'] = $this->parseForNull($row[13]);
        $deviceLog['14'] = $this->parseForNull($row[14]);
        $deviceLog['15'] = $this->parseForNull($row[15]);
        $deviceLog['16'] = $this->parseForNull($row[16]);
        $deviceLog['17'] = $this->parseForNull($row[17]);
        $deviceLog['18'] = $this->parseBoolean($row[18]);
        $deviceLog['19'] = $this->parseBoolean($row[19]);
        $deviceLog['20'] = $this->parseForNull($row[20]);
        $deviceLog['21'] = $this->parseBoolean($row[21]);
        if (!empty($row[22])) {
            $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y', $row[22]);
            **if($date->format('Y-m-d') != $nowYmd) {**
                continue;
            }
            $deviceLog['last_seen'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        } else {
            continue;
        }
```

How do i fix this? The upload is a csv file and the date can either be null/blanc or is in the following format :23-jan-17. As you can see by the code, the data is not supposed to be put in the database if the last_seen date is not today.

Ideas? Running laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check value of $row[22].
error will occurs if it is null.

```
if (!empty($row[22])) {
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y', $row[22]);
        if(!$date || ($date && ($date->format('Y-m-d') != $nowYmd))) {
            continue;
        }
        $deviceLog['last_seen'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: I think you're on to something here, but sadly "if (!empty($row[22]) && $row[22] != '')" gives the same error.
Any clues on how to fix that?

Comment: what is the value in $row[22] ?

Comment: Value is supposed to be 23-Jan-17, or well, null sometimes. But this code is supposed to make it not save the row if its not showing todays date etc. :)

Comment: Seems like it is working, thanks. Will update if something is odd about it but seems good. :)